# Is there a way to do dashed line in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi

I want to create a line chart on Power BI, grouped by months, that update every day. I want to have a dashed line only in the unfinished month, to show that the data is not full.

I have a table with daily bookings. I want to create a line graph on Power BI, that axis x will be month-year. The current month will be dashed and will include only the data since the first of the current month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a direct way in Power BI to do this, the closest that you can get to is to create the same measure twice to fake it. You'll need a way to identify the latest months data for a filter.
In the example that I have done, one measure is

Full Months = CALCULATE(SUM('MyTable'[Value]), FILTER('MyTable', 'MyTable'[Current] = 0))

and the other one is
Value = SUM('MyTable'[Value])

What I have done is show two measures, one on top of the other. You can update the chart formatting and select the 'Shapes' option' and select 'Customise series' and then select the measure name, and format as such.

[image]

You can set the legend to Off, and it will show like its one value.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Unfortunately I tried to do exactly the same, but I got a solid line for the history data and just a dot to the current month. I could not find a way to make the graph continuous. Any thoughts about the way to connect them?

Comment: It looks like you are filtering both lots of values, that would render  the incomplete month as a dot. Are you doing the following?

CALCULATE(SUM('MyTable'[Value]), FILTER('MyTable', 'MyTable'[Current] = 0))
and
CALCULATE(SUM('MyTable'[Value]), FILTER('MyTable', 'MyTable'[Current] = 1))
you should not be doing the CALCULATE(SUM('MyTable'[Value]), FILTER('MyTable', 'MyTable'[Current] = 1))


Or is there any other filter/slicer on the visual?
Only the one measure should be filtered

Comment: Jon, you were right all along! I have mistaken and used CALCULATE(SUM('MyTable'[Value]), FILTER('MyTable', 'MyTable'[Current] = 1)) instead of Value = SUM('MyTable'[Value]). Thanks!